# Validate Spring Hateoas Pageable param

Tags: java, spring, validation, elasticsearch, spring-hateoas

How should I valid Pageable parameter in Spring Hateoas? I.e. I have simple scenario (with Spring-Data-Elasticsearch):

```
public class Entity {
    private long timestamp;

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

---

```
    @Autowired
    private EntitiesRepository repository

    @RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Entity>>> list(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Entity> assembler){
        Page<Entity> entities = repository.findAll(pageable);
        PagedResources<Resource<Entity>> pagedResources = assembler.toResource(entities);
        return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Entity>>>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

All works fine if I pass valid value to sort param i.e. `localhost:8080/app/list?sort=timestamp`, but if value is wrong (given property doesn't exist) i.e. `localhost:8080/app/list?sort=name` elasticsearch exception is thrown :

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException
```

So, my question is: is any good practice to add validation of Pageable param?

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a way to validate a Pageable or Sort instance, but it looks like those can't be validated with @Valid or @Validated, even with your own validator. Spring simply never calls validate() on those specific parameters.

I guess the only way to perform validation is to extend PageableArgumentResolver or PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver to include the missing validation logic.